# Transformation of data with 0 values

Tags: regression, anova, data-transformation, count-data, zero-inflation

I've read some of the comments about trying to do log transformations on data that has 0 values. In my data I have two treatments that would be helped with a log transform except each treatment has a spike at or near 0, so I can't make the data normal. Can you still compare 2 such data sets with Anova if each one has a spike at 0? I can come close to normalizing the positive data. Since the 2 distributions look alike, do the two 0 spikes "cancel out" each other so that the Anova can still be done?

Comment: You can't make the data normal, but if they are skew then you can still consider other transformations such as log(y + 1), cube root or square root. Or a generalised linear model with log link which doesn't require transforming the response at all. Or it could be that the data are not too bad even as they come. But there is no sense in which the spikes "cancel out" -- from what you say the means will be biased upwards without them. Nor should they be omitted unless you have a strong scientific rationale for that.

Comment: What are the values of your response? Are they counts for example?  Are they (aside from the zeroes) continuous (like amount of daily rainfall or  amounts paid under insurance policies -- mostly 0 but when they're positive they are effectively continuous)? You may be able to do a similar analysis with a more suitable underlying model

Comment: The data consist of counts that can be any whole number starting with 0. I am trying to do a 3-way anova where treatments and species are fixed variabes, and blocks are a random variable. My primary interest is showing a significant interaction term between species and treatment. The data with a 0.2 power transform gives a highly significant result, but the large spike at 0 makes the distribution non-normal. I have also tried a rank transformation followed by anova, which also gives a high significance. But I don't know whether rank transformation is recommeded for showing interaction effects.

Comment: Maybe a zero-augmented count data model?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have count data (maybe zero augmented). Search this site for tags [zero-inflation](/questions/tagged/zero-inflation), [count-data](/questions/tagged/count-data) and [poisson-regression](/questions/tagged/poisson-regression). Rank transformation will not help, an (older) popular alternative with Poisson data is the square root transformation.

A good reference to start with is [Regression Models for Count Data in
R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/vignettes/countreg.pdf).